# create a json reponse from the controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, doctrine-orm, symfony

I try to create a JSON reponse in my controller for my ajax request. The purpose is : A user can write and post a comment without refresh the whole page. But after the ajax request, this request has to display the newly comment.

controller

```
public function viewAction(Request $request, Article $article, $slug, $page)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(CommentType::class, $comment);



    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
        }
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $comment->setAuthor($user);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $comment->setArticle($article);
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();

        $nbComments = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('PMPlatformBundle:Comment')
            ->getNbComments($article->getId())
        ;
        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => array(
            'nbComments'    => $nbComments,
            'newComment'   => $comment
        )));
    }
```

ajax in my view

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ path('pm_platform_view', {slug: article.slug}) }}',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data,
        success: function(objResponse) {
            $("#nbComments").html(objResponse.data.nbComments);
            $("#newComment").append(objResponse.data.newComment); //or somthing like that
        }
    });
});
```

Comment entity contains id, content, author (user id) and date of creation.

My ajax request works fine, the new comment is persisted in db, but now I have to display the new comment(s) in my view, so I have to create a good json reponse in the controller. However there is a problem with the reponse.

In the controller, do my JsonReponse is valid ? I mean I put the query result directly in the array and I don't now if is good or not for the jsonReponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fix it with :

```
    $data = array(
        'nbComments' => $nbComments,
        'comment' => $comment
    );

    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
    $normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('article'));
    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
    $dataJSON = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($dataJSON);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_encode method like below :-

```
json_encode([1, 2, 3]);
```

**Edited:**

Or you can use code like below :-

```
$items = array('nbComments' => $nbComments, 'newComments' => $newComments);
return new JsonResponse($items);
```

**Edited**

In success you can get it like with your current code :-

```
 $("#nbComments").html(objResponse.data[0].nbComments);
 $("#newComment").append(objResponse.data[1].newComments);
```

Comment: I thought the JsonResponse encode directly the args ? See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

Comment: ok, please use this JsonResponse('data' => array(
            'nbComments'    => $nbComments,
            'newComments'   => $newComments
        ))

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'  ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You want to display a newly added comment in a current site of the user who added it, right? 
In that case it is the best to write an "append" method tot he given container after the successful callback from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the error comes from your controller, and probably the normalization process.

You can try to dump the result of $newComments, which is probably a Doctrine ArrayCollection object.

You may be not convert it into a JsonResponse.

You have several options there:

You can try to use the [symfony normalizer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) to normalize our comments before passing it to JsonResponse:

```
$out = $this->get('serializer')->normalize($newComments, 'json');
return new JsonResponse($out);
```

If it's not working, try to dump your data just before the return. You may want to use the [symfony debugger](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug.html) or a component like [ladybug](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle)

Comment: I checked the Symfony debugger doc, explain me how to use this because the doc don't show that.. Whit using serializer service I got an exeption "A circular reference has been detected (configured limit: 1). " ...

Comment: Personally I use ladybug, and do `ldd($newComments)`.

For the circular reference, I think you have entity referencing another entity which refer to the first one. To avoid this, one solution is to use [the group annotations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
        public function json($data){
    $normalizers=array(new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer());
    $encoders = array ("json"=>new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder());

    $serializer = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

    //Convierte la respuesta en un HTTP
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    $response->setContent($json);

    $response->headers->set("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return $response;
}
```

This should work fine